# Cannot Access Custom App

Tags: lightning-apps, permissions, custom

I've created a custom application but users are unable to access it. The app has every profile enabled, the users profiles settings are enabled for this app, and the app menu also has this app set to present. The admin can view the app, but no other users.

Any ideas how to provide access?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Console layout and needed to create a custom permission set that allowed the user to view console apps. License = lightning console & system permission = **Lightning Console App User**.